# How to force glob() to make result in numerical order?

Tags: sort

I have next files in the directory:

```
ls -1 file_*

file_1
file_101
file_2
file_202
file_3
file_4
file_5
```

In **Vim** I want to have these files in a numerically ordered list, like so:

```
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 'file_101', 'file_202']
```

But `glob()` function returns this:

```
echo glob('file_*', 0, 1)

" Result
['file_1', 'file_101', 'file_2', 'file_202', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5']
```

I have found a workaround

```
function! Compare(i1, i2) 
    let l:f = str2nr(matchstr(a:i1, '[0-9]\+'))
    let l:s = str2nr(matchstr(a:i2, '[0-9]\+'))
    return l:f == l:s ? 0 : l:f > l:s ? 1 : -1
endfunction

echo sort(glob('file_*', 0, 1), 'Compare')

" Result
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 'file_101', 'file_202']
```

but interested, is it possible to force `glob()` function to work as I want?

Comment: Ultimately, if you need a sorted order, you have to sort... you might be able to pull some tricks with LANG (it affects sorted order for at least the sort utility), but you’re better off with what you have I expect